# how to combine multiple mySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm newbie in mySQL. I have multiple queries sql to combine and I'm using php and mySQL. How can I combine the query? All result of the query I need to display in one row of a table.

```html
<?php
$query1="SELECT s.staffName, s.staffNo, g.grade, g.gradePosition, g.gradeDepartment 
   FROM tblstaff s, tblgrade g where s.staffNo=g.staffNo";  
 $result=mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());  
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 ?>
  <td><?php echo $row['staffName']; ?></td> <!--display staff name-->
  <td><?php echo $row['staffNo']; ?></td> <!--display staff number-->
  <td><?php echo $row['grade']; ?></td> <!--display staff grade-->
  <td><?php echo $row['gradePosition']; ?></td> <!--display staff position-->
  <td><?php echo $row['gradeDepartment']; ?></td><!--display staff department-->
  <tr>
 
<?php
  }
?> 

<?php
$query2="select catTechnical, catOtherTechnical, catTechnicalDescription, catOtherTechnicalDescription, catWeightage,
   perReqScore  
   from tblcategory c join tblperformance p on c.catID=p.catID"; 
 $result=mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error()); 
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 ?>
  <td><?php echo $row['catTechnical']; ?></td> <!--display technical category-->
  <td><?php echo $row['catTechnicalDescription']; ?></td> <!--display technical description-->
  <td><?php echo $row['catOtherTechnicalDescription']; ?></td> <!--display other technical description-->
  <td><?php echo $row['catWeightage']; ?></td> <!--display weightage-->
  <td><?php echo $row['perReqScore']; ?></td <!--display required score-->
<?php
}
?>
```

This is my database tables.

**tblstaff**

```html
+---------+-----------+
| staffNo | staffName |
+---------+-----------+
| 1002435 | Fadzlan   |
+---------+-----------+
```

**tblgrade**

```html
+---------+---------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
| gradeID | staffNo | grade | gradePosition | gradeDepartment |
+---------+---------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1 | 1002435 | E14   | Manager       | IB              |
+---------+---------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
```

**tblcategory**

```html
+-------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| catID | catTechnical |     catOtherTechnical     | catTechnicalDescription | catWeightage |
+-------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
|    18 | Project(18)  | Project Coordination(181) |                      30 |              |
+-------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

**tblperformance**

```html
+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
| perID | catID | staffNo  | perReqScore |
+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
|     1 |    18 | 10028531 |           4 |
+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

This is my current code and database table. I need to combine query 1 and query 2 because I want to display the result in one row of a table by staffNo. I means one staffNo for one row in a table. Then other staffNo will display into a new row of the same table.

Comment: Yana Rina - the code that you gave here just assigns a string to a PHP (Ithink) variable. Show also how you execute it.

Comment: `UNION` can be used here if you are looking to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements .

Comment: please post your tables structure and a sample of what you want to retrieve, from what you described you may need UNION or JOIN to get what you wanted.

Comment: How many tables do you need to join? Do you need all rows from all tables or only rows with the same id?

Comment: There are 4 tables I need to join which are table tblstaff, tblgrade, tblcategory and tblperformance. My third query is joining for two table which is table category and table performance. I need to display rows with the same id @User_T

Comment: join tblperformance with tblstaff  as `join tblperformance p on s.staffNo=p.staffNo` other things already joined.. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your third query, it's not clear which columns are in which table. Since you say that all results need to display in one row, I assume s.staffNo = g.staffNo is true only for one row pair, and also that c.catID = p.catID is true for only one row pair. Then you can just use JOIN. I would suggest adding the short table names though. UNION will not work because that is for combining row sets of equal length and equal column types.

Edit: Added `c.` and `p.` Please don't use `mysql_query`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_query` instead. I'm not sure if this database is designed in the best way possible. Can't you just merge everything into tblstaff?

```
SELECT s.staffName, s.staffNo, g.grade, g.gradePosition, g.gradeDepartment, 
c.catTechnical, c.catOtherTechnical, c.catTechnicalDescription, c.catOtherTechnicalDescription, c.catWeightage, p.perReqScore, p.perActScore, p.perAction, p.perOtherAction, p.perTrainingIlsas, p.perTrainingPublic
FROM tblstaff s
JOIN tblgrade g ON s.staffNo = g.staffNo
JOIN tblcategory c
JOIN tblperformance p on c.catID = p.catID
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning in the question. My third query is joining from two tables which is tblcategory and tblperformance by staffNo. I had updated my previous question if you want to see my code. Tq

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.staffName, s.staffNo, g.grade, g.gradePosition, g.gradeDepartment,
   c.catTechnical, c.catOtherTechnical, c.catTechnicalDescription, 
   c.catOtherTechnicalDescription, c.catWeightage, c.perReqScore, c.perActScore, 
   c.perAction, c.perOtherAction, c.perTrainingIlsas, c.perTrainingPublic
FROM tblstaff s, tblgrade g, tblcategory c
JOIN tblperformance p on c.catID = p.catID
WHERE s.staffNo = g.staffNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have done all already except `join tblperformance p on s.staffNo=p.staffNo`

```
SELECT s.staffName, s.staffNo, g.grade, g.gradePosition, g.gradeDepartment 
c.catTechnical, c.catOtherTechnical, c.catTechnicalDescription,
c.catOtherTechnicalDescription, c.catWeightage, p.perReqScore

FROM tblstaff s
join tblgrade g on s.staffNo=g.staffNo
join tblperformance p on s.staffNo=p.staffNo
join tblcategory c on p on c.catID=p.catID
```